# How did Five avoid being spaced by Three?

Tags: dark-matter

Midway through episode 6 of Dark Matter, there is a scene where Five is reliving one of her memories.  This one in particular involves Three having resolved to "space" her.  That is, stuff her in an airlock and vent it to space.  The scene changes before anything happens, but obviously we know Five didn't die, or she wouldn't be alive enough to be reliving the memory.

Is it ever revealed how Five survives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in a flashback at the beginning of the twelfth episode Six showed up and opened the airlock at the last second; when Six confronts him Three says he was "Just trying to scare her", that he never really intended to space Five.